# Connecting multiple devices with UART

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, uart

So, I have the following components:

[Gertbot](http://www.gertbot.com/)

[SparqEE Shield](http://www.sparqee.com/portfolio/sparqee-shieldr/)

My aim is to connect these to a Raspberry Pi Model B+, so that they can work together.

There are no issues when I connect these individually to the Pi, however when I try to use them at the same time from a Python program, I get a 'Resource is temporarily unavailable' error, which is understandable since the Pi's UART would be in use by one of the devices.

I can power both devices perfectly fine, by putting the SparqEE shield (which has a SparqEE cell connected to it) directly onto the Pi's GPIO pins and then connecting the Gertbot to the top of the Shield with a raised header.

I also have an FTDI RPi hub module, which has two UART interfaces, which I hoped could connect the Gertbot to the Raspberry Pi over USB, but I am unable to get this to work properly. The RPi HUB powers on fine when connected to a USB port, and my keyboard and mouse connects to it. I cannot find any documentation on the pin layout of the RPi HUB module, so if someone could also point me to that, it would be very much appreciated.

So, my questions to you are, how can I get these two devices to play nicely together? Am I connecting them in the wrong way? Are the pins on these devices laid out in some standardized fashion, or is there someway to tell the pins apart?

Many thanks in advance for any answers or help, and I apologize for any poor explanations or terminology in my questions, I am new to using the Raspberry Pi and GPIO.

Comment: Does the FTDI documentation at http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Modules/DS_RPi_HUB_Module.pdf answer your pinout questions?